# Badge notifications use incorrect image sprite

Tags: discussion, badges, images

If I'm on [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), and I open the achievements dialog in the top bar (*I know there's a given name for this, but I don't recall it), the badge icon used will be from the sprite image of the current site. e.g., if on Programmers SE, you get the badge icon from [this sprite](http://cdn.sstatic.net/programmers/img/sprites.png) for a badge earned on Stack Overflow, which uses [this sprite](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png). Another example is the [Mathematics SE image sprite](https://cdn.sstatic.net/math/img/sprites.png), which also uses significantly different icons for badges.

Perhaps each site's badge icons could be in a common file, such as the [favicon sprite](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png)? You would not need to include icons for all sites, since most use the common bronze, silver, and gold circles found in the [Meta SE sprite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/stackexchangemeta/img/sprites.png).